# Invalid android_key parameter - Using gamemaker

Tags: android, android-keystore

Im getting the Invalid android_key parameter error when trying to post to facebook, I have added the key hash in the error to the key hash section on my app but still no luck. Im baffled. Any help would be great. Thanksss

Comment: Have you set your application/server key in Google Console? Added your permissions in your manifest?

Comment: Where do i add the app/server key in the console? sorry new to all this

Comment: Go to console.developers.google.com and create a new project. Once done, click APIs & auth. Click Credentials. Click create new key. The "Learn More" link near the create new key button really helps

Comment: i don't see how that links to my android application though ?

Comment: Set your key with a meta tag in your manifest. There's some good guides on Google keys if you search a bit